# __LINE__ macro not working when define printf's macro

Tags: c++, macros, printf

The **LINE** macro gives random number and **FILE** macro gives a null when, the "printf" is defined with another macro. In the following code, I have shown the macro used for "printf" and the function (which is a method of a class), where the macro is used:

```
#define OTConsolePrint(x) printf(x)
```

...

```
void parseArray(float* arr)
{
    if (arr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Line: %d\n", __LINE__);
        OTConsolePrint("Null pointer at \nLine: %d\nFile: %s\n", __LINE__, __FILE__);
    }
}
```

gives me:

```
Line: 39
Null pointer at
Line: 1964696
File: (null)
```

Comment: That's undefined behaviour

Comment: This seems like invalid code. Please post the full code, and tell us which compiler you are using.

Comment: *Macros* and *printf* are pratically *C* code. I suggest you to use *variadic template* instead. Anyway your code is wrong because `OTConsolePrint` takes one single argument. I don't even know how that code should compile

Comment: It worked with Visual studio. I din't give any build error though.

Comment: Where's your [MCVE]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "*macro-function*" takes just one argument:

```
#define OTConsolePrint(x) printf(x)
```

You call it, instead, with more than one argument:

```
OTConsolePrint("Null pointer at \nLine: %d\nFile: %s\n", __LINE__, __FILE__);
```

Actually I don't even think it compiles.

---

Anyway in order to have *variadic* argument you can do:

```
#define OTConsolePrint(STR, ...) printf(STR, __VA_ARGS__)
```

It [works](https://ideone.com/WwjwDH) as expected.

Answer (score 2):

```
#define OTConsolePrint(x, y, z) printf(x, y, z)
```

When you call the macro in the function you pass three elements.